# Azure polybase external data source creation error

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, polybase

I am trying to create an external table in synapse analytics, but I am facing error while creating the external data source.

Below is the code:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='xxxxxxxxxxxx'; -- executed

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL storageCred WITH       -- executed
IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', 
SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE adls WITH                    -- execution failed
(  TYPE = HADOOP, 
   LOCATION = 'abfss://staging@devedw2021.dfs.core.windows.net', 
   CREDENTIAL = storageCred
)
```

[image: error]

Comment: Can you try with `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [myadls] WITH (LOCATION = 'abfss://staging@devedw2021.dfs.core.windows.net', CREDENTIAL = storageCred, TYPE = HADOOP );`? Name is myadls instead of adls, it's put inside `[]` to avoid any keyword conflict, order of params inside is same [as in example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated#examples-1). Select and run only this command (not along with any other commands).

Comment: What kind is your datalake? v1, v2, Gen2?

Comment: @Kashyap- It's ADLS Gen-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks right for the External Data Source, but the problem may be with the Database Scoped Credential. I spent a LOT of time on this, and the only way I could get this to work was with Account name and key:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL CausewayAdlsCredentials
WITH
 IDENTITY = '<storage_account_name>' ,
 SECRET = '<storage_account_key>'
;
```

One word of warning: beware the documentation. There are several different locations that discuss this problem, and they have conflicting messaging or refer to old versions. [This one is OK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&tabs=dedicated), but only section C worked for me.

Comment: I am not sure, but I have changed from "Serverless Pool" to "Dedicated SQL Pool" in Synapse then it started working.